# Creative triangle stacks using for loops

Tags: java

I was wondering if someone can help me out with achieving the following result (using for loops):

```
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
```

This is the code that I have written:

```
public static void drawBody1(){
  for (int line = 1; line <= 3; line++){
      System.out.print("|");
      for (int dot = 1; dot <= (-1 * line + 3); dot++){
        System.out.print(".");
      }
      for (int mount = 1; mount <= line; mount++){
        System.out.print("/\\");
      }
      for (int dot = 1; dot <= (-2 * line + 6); dot++){
        System.out.print(".");
      }
      for (int mount = 1; mount <= line; mount++){
        System.out.print("/\\");
      }
      for (int dot = 1; dot <= (-1 * line + 3); dot++){
        System.out.print(".");
      }
      System.out.print("|");
      System.out.println();
  }
```

Although I did get the figure above, I realize that the code abounds in redundancy and is, thus, far from efficient.

I was hoping if someone can show me a simple yet elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Maybe draw the "left part" (i.e. `|./\/\.`) and draw it after "reversed" (i.e. `./\/\.|`). But this code is readable so you probably should stick to that

Comment: Draw periods, draw left carets, redraw periods, redraw everything would also be a viable solution.

Comment: This would only shorten your code a tiny bit, but you do not need to use braces if your `for-loop` only executes 1 line

Comment: @GoJava It's recommended to [always put brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020255/7756856) even if it's just to avoid really difficult to debug mistakes later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a method, so it is easy to adjust the height of the pyramid, and the output it gives is just as you asked. This code is shorter and easier to understand in my opinion(maybe just because I wrote it), but the main difference is that it is easy to change the height of your pyramid. I named my function `drawMounts(int height)`. Try changing `height` in the main method, and you will see that the pyramids easily adjust. This program makes one line at a time, prints it and repeats but the line changes slightly. `height` can be even or odd, it works the same. Here's the program:

```
public class Experiments {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawMounts(3);
    }
    private static void drawMounts(int height) {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            String line = "";
            String ends = "";
            String middle = ".";
            String mount = "";
            System.out.print("|");
            for(int j = i; j < (height-1); j++)
                middle += "..";
            for (int dot = i; dot < (height-1); dot++)
                ends += ".";
            for(int body = (i+1); body > 0; body--)
                mount += "/\\";
            line = ends + mount + middle + mount + ends;
            System.out.print(line);
            System.out.println("|");
        }   
    }
}
```

And here's the output when `height` is equal to 3:

```
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\|
```

And this is when `height` is 6, just so you get an idea of what changing `height` does:

```
|...../\........../\.....|
|..../\/\......../\/\....|
|.../\/\/\....../\/\/\...|
|../\/\/\/\..../\/\/\/\..|
|./\/\/\/\/\../\/\/\/\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\|
```

Comment: StringBuilder would be preferred

Comment: Do you mean like drawing half the line, then reversing it for the second half? I don't think this would make much of a difference

Comment: No, I just mean instead of `+=` within any loops

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh okay

Comment: Interesting solution - a bit more advanced than what I am allowed to do for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Karli What do you think is complicated? I would be glad to explain. Is this answer acceptable?

Comment: this was only a part of the bigger picture - drawing a rocket, which upon completion needs to be scaled entering a single number (part of the learning how to use constants in java)...the whole code looks like this:

Comment: Well you can rename the function to `drawPart` or something and just set `height` to 3. This is the beauty of functions. Call them whenever you want and change them however you want. Glad I could help make your rocket!